# Ungroup an EMF/EPS picture file to a Microsoft Office Drawing Object in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, .emf, vba

I've got some VBA code which inserts an EPS picture to a PowerPoint slide as follows:

```
Function InsertPicture(filename as String) As Shape
    Dim curSlide As Integer
    Dim oShp As Shape, gShp As Shape
    curSlide = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(curSlide).Shapes
        Set oShp = .AddPicture(filename, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0)
        ' Convert (by ungrouping) from EPS to Microsoft Office drawing object
        oShp.Ungroup.Name = "GroupEPS"
        ' Return the new Microsoft Office drawing object
        Set InsertPicture = ActivePresentation.Slides(curSlide).Shapes("GroupEPS")
    End With
End Sub
```

The equivalent insert picture function for Excel is this:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filename).Select
```

Or this if a reference to the object is required:

```
Dim oPic as Object
Set oPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filename)
```

But when I try to ungroup it with the following line, I get an error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

```
' For a selection
Selection.Ungroup
' For an object
oPic.Ungroup.Name = "GroupEPS"
```

However, if I right click on the picture that was correctly inserted into the sheet I can successfully ungroup it, after confirming the conversion to a Microsoft Office drawing object.

Why does the UI allow ungrouping but Excel VBA doesn't (while PowerPoint VBA does) and is there a way round this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how EPS shapes are dealt with, but I'm guessing Excel treats it as an OLE object. Can you debug and check the shape type you're trying to ungroup in Excel? If you want to ungroup only grouped shapes, the shape type should be msoGroup.

Comment: Right, after a bit more playing, I can get it to work by creating an instance of PowerPoint,creating a new presentation, adding a slide, inserting the EPS picture, ungrouping it, copying the converted drawing object to the clipboard and pasting it to excel, where it appears as a group of shapes in the Selection Pane.

Comment: But this all takes a huge amount of time and is very clunky.

I have uploaded an example EPS file I'm using here:

http://i-present.co.uk/stackoverflow/b1-034-034_telephone.eps

If I insert this into a PowerPoint slide and use activewindow.selection.ungroup it works but the same is not true for Excel, for which I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method". Weird. One would have thought that two MSO apps would use the same mechanism when treating this type of media content!

And for the type, I get 2 (ppselectionshapes) in PowerPoint but the same error above for Excel.

Comment: It seems Excel just doesn't like EPS files but then why is it still possible to manually ungroup the same EPS file when it's inserted via the UI to the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once to get the thing ungrouped and leave it selected, leaving you with the b/g object and the other objects in a group; then again to ungroup to its components and leave them selected:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup.Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup.Select
```

Tested it on a couple different simple EPS imports and an EMF/WMF; works with all of them.

Understand, though, that the way Office handles EPS is something of an abortion; always has been.  At least this time round, they do the wrong thing for generally right reasons.

Comment: That looks like it works thanks Steve :-) I'm currently trying the same thing in Word where things are yet again different due to InlineShapes and Shapes layers!

set oShp = App.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(filename,false,true,0,0,50,50)
oShp.Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup.Select 'error 5

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess!

```
Sub unGrp()
Dim opic As ShapeRange
Dim filename As String
filename = "C:\Users\John\Desktop\telephone.eps"
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filename).Select
Set opic = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
opic.Ungroup
End Sub
```